# htaccess, url must have the www in it or re-direct

Tags: .htaccess

I need to re-direct a url of a website of mine, if it hasn't the www in it, because of a script that dont work if the url isn't complete, how can i do this with a htacces file, I cant find an example on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work for you:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?!www\.)(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)
RewriteRule .? http://www.%1%2 [R=301,L]
```